# I have a question about the dimension of the Kernel of a transposed matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonality

I've been studying linear algebra and I came across this reasoning that is certainly not correct, but I can't see why. If A is a matrix, I know that $$Row(A)^{\perp} = Kernel(A)$$. Consequently, $$Col(A)^{\perp} = Kernel(A^T)$$ I also know that $$dim(Row(A)) = dim(Col(A))$$. It would be natural for me to assume that if the above is true, it should be true that $$dim(Row(A))^{\perp} = dim(Col(A))^{\perp}$$ This would imply that the dimension of the kernel of A (nullity of A) is equal to the dimension of the kernel of its transpose, which is not the case unless A is a square matrix. Where is the flaw in this reasoning? Thank you all in advance!

Comment: according to this , null space and left null space must be the same but they are not :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For subspaces $U \subset \Bbb R^m$ and $V \subset \Bbb R^n$, it is not the case that $\dim(U) = \dim(V)$ implies that $\dim(U^\perp) = \dim(V^\perp)$. Note that $\dim(U^\perp) = m - \dim(U)$ and $\dim(V^\perp) = n - \dim(V)$, so we will only have $\dim(U^\perp) = \dim(V^\perp)$ if $m=n$.